# Switch off their grey matter before parking on the couch

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-usage

When I read a [news](https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-62148480) article I came across the below sentence.

> The Telegraph described the show, which is released on Thursday, as "riotously ridiculous" and "great fun for those who like to **switch off their grey matter before parking on the couch**".

Although I know grey matter is a part in brain and guess this might be a metaphor, I have no idea how to interpret this sentence.

Are there anybody who can tell me what the highlighted part in this sentence means?

Comment: Yes it's a metaphor, grey matter = brain. You could reword the highlighted phrase as: *chill out/relax before sitting for a long time on the couch (or sofa)*.  *Parking* is also being used figuratively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a metaphor for the intelligence. The reviewer is saying that, to enjoy the show, when you sit down to watch TV you have to forget about analysing the story seriously and just let yourself be entertained.

Comment: Thank you very much :)